# Auto-correlation function, an inverse problem

Tags: fourier-analysis, computer-science, inverse, time-series, inverse-problems

$x[n]$ is a complex function $n=0,1,2,\cdots,L-1 $

we assume $x[n]$ is periodic in its index:  $x[n+L]=x[n]$

Its auto-correlation function $C[n]$ is **uniquely** defined as:
$$
C[n]=\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} x[i+n]x^*[i]
$$
$C[n]$ also has the periodic property: $$C[n+L]=C[n]\tag{1}$$

And ''conjugate-symmetry'' property: $C[-n]=C^*[n] \tag{2}$

---

#### Now my question is:

For given $C[n]$, which satisfies property (1) and (2):

**Can** we find the corresponding $x[n]$ ?

If yes, is it unique?

$\qquad $ if unique, what is the method to find $x[n]$?

$\qquad $ if not unique, what is the class of those $C[n] \rightarrow \{x[n]\}$

If no, what other constraint properties should we add to $C[n]$, in order to make it yes?

---

Comment: You probably need to ask another question instead of saying "now my question is" and link to it from this one to follow proper etiquette. The second question is much broader. Also, if you have a preference between the answers,  maybe accept one. Otherwise the system thinks the question is unanswered, while it most certainly has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### my guess

No, we can't find $x[n]$ from general $C[n]$

In order to make it yes, we need the discrete Fourier transform of $C[n]$ to be semi-positive defined.

$$I[\omega] \geqslant 0  \tag{3}\\
\text{where} \qquad
\omega=0,1,2,\cdots,L-1 \\
and \qquad 
I[\omega]=\text{DFT}[C[n]]:=\sum_{n=0}^{L-1} C[n] e^{\frac{2\pi i}{L}\omega n}
$$
By the way, $I(\omega)$ is real as the result of "conjugate-symmetric" property of $C[n]$

(3) is extra condition to make the $x[n]$ exist for given $C[n]$

---

with constraint (1),(2),(3)  together. The answer is yes.

But the solution $x[n]$ are not unique.

They are not unique up to $L$ phases factors:  $\theta[\omega] \quad \omega =0,1,2,\cdots,L-1$
$$
\tilde{x}[\omega]=\text{DFT}[x[n]]= |\tilde{x}[\omega]| e^{i\theta[\omega]}
$$

$$
I[\omega]= |\tilde{x}[\omega]|^2
$$

$\tilde{x}[\omega]$ is the Fourier transform of $x[n]$, knowing $\tilde{x}[\omega]$ then we know $x[n]$

however, when we recover $\tilde{x}[\omega]$ from $I[\omega]$, the phase information $\theta[\omega]$ is completely missing. which makes $x[n]$ not unique.

---

#### In sum:

$C[n] \xrightarrow{DFT} I[\omega]$

If $I[\omega]$ is **not** semi-positive defined, then there is no solution for $x[n]$

If $I[\omega]$ is semi-positive defined, then there are solutions of $x[n]$, and they are not unique, up to $L$ phase factors.

$\tilde{x}[\omega]$ is the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of $x[n]$. DFT is a one-to-one mapping.

$
I[\omega]= |\tilde{x}[\omega]|^2
$

and then  $\tilde{x}[\omega] \xrightarrow{\text{inverse} DFT} x[n]$

since $\tilde{x}[\omega]$ is not unique, up to phase factor $|\tilde{x}[\omega]| e^{i\theta[\omega]}$, our $x[n]$ is also not unique.

---

Above is my guess.

Maybe there are already some textbook conclusions from some part of the math I don't know.

So, I hope to get some reference from this subject.

Answer (score 3):

Even up to shifts it is not unique at all. For example there is a whole collection of sequences called $m-$sequences (maximal length sequences) generated by binary linear shift registers corresponding to primitive polynomials. See the discussion [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence).

There are $\phi(2^n-1)/n$ different primitive polynomials over the binary field of degree $n$ and each of these give rise to an $m-$sequence (and all its shifts). All these sequences have period $2^n-1$ and ideal autocorrelation
$$C_t=-1+\delta(t)2^n$$
where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Kronecker delta.

Corresponding complex valued sequences exist for non-binary fields, over $GF(p)$ they are sequences over complex roots of unity of order $p.$

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not unique.
Consider the real sequences $x_0 = 0, x_1 =1$ and $y_0=1, y_1=0$ (in both cases $L=2$).

Then for $x$:

$$C_0 = x_0^2+x_1^2 =1,$$
$$C_1 = x_1x_0 + x_0x_1 = 0,$$
$$C_2 = x_0^2+x_1^2 = 1,$$
$$C_3 = x_1x_0 + x_0x_1 = 0...$$

While for $y$:

$$C_0 = y_0^2+y_1^2 =1,$$
$$C_1 = y_1y_0 + y_0y_1 = 0,$$
$$C_2 = y_0^2+y_1^2 = 1,$$
$$C_3 = y_1y_0 + y_0y_1 = 0...$$

The two sequences are shifted. In general, all shifted sequences share the same auto-correlation function. Thus, it is hard to add constraints to get a unique sequence.